# Why is this line $Pv-v$?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

This is an image from page 42 of Trefethen and Bau.

$P$ is a projection operator.

Why is the line connecting the vectors $v$ and $Pv$ equal to $Pv-v$? I know the rules of vector addition and it seems to me that $Pv-v$ is a vector of the same length as denoted in the image but originating from $(0,0)$, obtained by adding $Pv$ and $-v$ using parallelogram law of vector addition.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y11bv.jpg

Comment: You can think of a vector in Euclidean space as a directed line segment, or an arrow, where two arrows are considered equal (the same vector) if they have the same length and the same direction. Note that $x-y = (x+s)-(y+s)$.

Comment: You are in fact quite correct about vector addition. Now, notice that $v+(Pv-v)=Pv$. Try to picture this equation in the diagram. Can you see that parallelogram?

Comment: @user3733558 I can see it, only if I shift $Pv-v$ downwards, so that it begins from the origin and is directed away from the origin, towards the left, in the third quadrant.

Comment: I agree with you, in that I also prefer to have vectors starting at the origin if we're working with vector spaces. Not sure why the authors of that book chose to go with that representation (perhaps they think it is more intuitive). The point we're trying to make is that the diagram displays a vector which is exactly the same length and direction.

Comment: Yes, after I absorbed the fact that the translated representation of a vector represents the same vector — as mentioned in an answer here — I understood, visually why the diagram is like it is.

Answer (score 1):

For any two vector $a,b$, the line joining $a$ to $b$ is a representant of the vector $b-a$. **Remember that the translated representation of any vector represents the same vector.** In mathematical terms

$$(b+c) - (a+c) = b-a$$ for any $c$.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this — that the translated representation of any vector represents the same vector?

Comment: See the equation that I added.

Comment: Okay, it makes sense now. Thanks.